# Use an HTML file as a CSS file

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use an HTML file with CSS throught this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myfile.html" />
```

I cannot access to the server and make new files so the server provides the option to create HTML files and I wanna use them as CSS hosts. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe it would be better not to use a crappy hosting company restricting you like that? Sounds a bit like you are using some kind of free webspace...

Comment: You have to manipulate the file content. If you youse php you can use .htaccess to show php file as html and header("Content-type:CSS") to show php the page as CSS file

Comment: @ThiefMaster If it was my chose I wouldn't use it, but it's not my decision.

Comment: @budamivardi I haven't got any access to the server.

Comment: I think this is not possible without any access to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to include the html containing css in the other html so myCssfile.html is :

```
<style>
//enter CSS code here
</style>
```

and then your main html file:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("myCssFile.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

I'm using here the JQuery function .load but it probably can be done with pure JS

Comment: If you *really* ***really*** want to resort to a jQuery option, at least append the type tag somewhere inside the `<head>`

Comment: It's a really nice option if none of this works but I'd like to use the HTML/CSS option if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the file contents are valid CSS and the `type` attribute is set correctly, then the browser will believe you that it's a CSS file and will parse/use it as such.

Comment: I've tried it but it's not working. The console returns this error: 'La hoja de estilos (link) no se ha cargado porque su tipo MIME, "text/html", no es "text/css"', what in English I think that means 'The stylesheet (link) hasn't be loaded because it's type MIME "text/html" it's not "text/css"'.